# How to display warning message if user make change in the page and decide to leave this page in JSF application?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jsf, bootstrap-modal

I'm in a JSF2.0 application which has many jsf files, each page could has inputs + some selectMenu . I want a concrete solution on how **to display a warning message (as a Modal)** when the user makes some changes in this current page (filling some inputs for example) and decide to visit other pages or close the current tabs.

Comment: "I need this functionality asap." We all need our answers yesterday.

Comment: And I need more money

Answer (score 0):

So there's a few parts to this.

First of all to create the modal you need a hidden div. You then need some JQuery that will detect any changes made to then pop this modal up.

You can do this by having a div looking like this with the CSS below as well:

**HTML**

```
<div class="modal hide">
<p>Content here...</p>
<button class="close">Close</button>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.hide{
  display: none;
}
.modal{
  position: fixed;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100px;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Then add a class to anything that needs to be alerted when changed. If it's an input that has to be filled out just add the required attribute shown below For example:

```
<input type="text" name="example" class="change" required>
```

Then you can use JQuery to detect any changes and display the modal:

**JQuery**

```
$(".change").on("change", function(){
    $(".modal").removeClass("hide");
});
$(".close").on("click", function(){
    $(".modal").addClass("hide");
});
```

This then shows the modal with a button that gives the option to close it.

In regards to on leaving the page this is much more complex as you could end up giving a warning upon the user successfully submitting a form. Not to mention the user experience issues. Please refer to this answer here: [Detect browser or tab closing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3888902/detect-browser-or-tab-closing/3888938#3888938)

I've also put together a working JSFiddle for you here - https://jsfiddle.net/Rockhopper92/vsmLkqLm/

Comment: I think https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/ was requested by the OP. And your answer does not **cover** unsubmitted data.

Comment: You're right it doesn't. Don't need JQuery for that just updated the answer now. Also hadn't picked up on the specific bootstrap modal part but this would still be a solution. Also nothing to stop you adding your own classes into a bootstrap modal I've done it many times.